# Returning Associated Members via Ria DomainService Invoke Method

Tags: silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0, rich-internet-application, domainservices

I got this DomainService method I'm calling from my SL ViewModel using the Invoke attribute:

```
[Invoke]
public ServiceModel.Recipy GetRecipyById(int recipyId)
{
    return new Recipy
                {
                    RecipyId = 1,
                    Name = "test",
                    Description = "desc",
                    Author = new Author
                                {
                                    AuthorId = 1,
                                    Name = "Johan"
                                }
                };
}
```

The code in my ViewModel looks like this:

```
public RecipyViewModel()
{
    context.GetRecipyById(1, RecipyLoadedCallback, null);
}

private void RecipyLoadedCallback(InvokeOperation<Recipy> obj)
{
    _name = obj.Value.Name;
    _description = obj.Value.Description;
    _authorName = obj.Value.Author.Name;
}
```

The Recipy and Author POCO/ServiceModel classes:

```
public class Recipy
{
    [Key]
    public int RecipyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Association("Author", "RecipyId", "AuthorId")]
    [Include]
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the code works fine, except that the associated Author is not transfered over to the client/viewmodel, the Author property of Recipy is null. I thought that using the [Associate] and [Include] attributes would do the trick?

Thanks for any help, I'm trying hard to grok the DomainService/RIA stuff and I'm close to giving up and go "normal" WCF/REST instead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, [Invoke] doesn't support complex hierarchies at the moment, so I solved it by making sure I had the correct attributes for [Include] and [Association] on the collection, and went back to using a normal RIA query method instead.